# How can I generate DDL scripts from Entity Framework 4.3 Code-First Model?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3

I have a project I'm trying to deploy and I'm using a cheap host to get started.  As part of the hosting package I have a SQL Server database, but I don't have drop or create privileges, I can only use the database they've created for me.  Being that's the case, I want to get the DDL so I can run it manually.

I'm aware I could script the database create scripts from SQL Management Studio, and that may ultimately work fine, but I'd like to automate the process as much as possible, so if I could get the scripts that Entity Framework creates, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate the script using

```
Update-Database -Script
```

(from the Package Manager Console)

You can find further details in [this walkthrough](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx), which also describes some of the additional options you might need.

Comment: Is this a command line tool?  If you can elaborate enough that I can find how to execute this command, I will mark as answer.

Comment: It's a PS script... you can run it from the package management console.

Comment: Updated - as Diego says, this is run from the Nuget Console window.

Comment: @Richard this only seems to run if you have migrations (error:No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly)? Can you use it to get a raw dump of the whole DDL?

Comment: No, you need to enable migrations (Update-Database is the command to apply migrations).

Comment: This link is now dead.

Comment: @Mr.Boy you can reach it at https://web.archive.org/web/20120516212458/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx

Not sure it's very helpful though, as EF has changed a lot.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d).

I also wrote a tiny open source tool for that, [EFScripter](https://github.com/diegose/EFScripter).

It takes two parameters: connection string (it can be as simple as `"Integrated Security=SSPI"` if you have a local instance of SQL Server), and the dll containing the DbContext.

It writes the script to the standard output.