# How and when does Entity Framework Code First generate the DB?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I came across this related question: [How can I generate DDL scripts from Entity Framework 4.3 Code-First Model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466041/how-can-i-generate-ddl-scripts-from-entity-framework-4-3-code-first-model)

But this doesn't appear to answer the question of when a Code First application actually checks the existence/correctness of the DB and modifies it if necessary. Is it at run-time or build time? Assuming it's at run-time is it at start-up or when you create the DbContext or at the last possible moment e.g. when you try to write/read the DB table(s) it checks they exist on a case-by-case basis?

Answer (score 1):

It is ceated at rutime the first time you access an entity, ie,

```
using (var db = new MyDBContext())
{
   var items = db.MyObj.Count() // <- Here it is created!
}
```

There are some flavors on how, like if you set the creating strategy to CreateDatabaseIfNotExists, DropCreateDatabaseAlways, Etc. Please give this a look:

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: the initialization is actually highly dependant on the initialization strategy, not just "flavors"! In the predefined strategies the database is checked against the model by looking at the __MigrationHistory table (if not DropCreateDatabaseAlways) at context initialization, however not in user-defined initializers. The initializer is run right after model building, and within this the creation of a database with the correct schema has to be taken care of. So its not like some weird gimmick, but actually what the initializer is all about.

Comment: You are right, but the "Here it is created" is where it is actually checked and that answers the question. Ie, when all the "magic" is done. Of course, many details on how/when depends on your implementation.

Comment: of course, since there the initializer is run. However, since you mentioned the initialization strategies, you should have mentioned that the implementation of these initializers is the source of this "magic".

Answer (score 0):

The column Model in the table *__MigrationHistory* is serialized and gzipped(base64) version of your *EDMX*. In code first the column Model is generated by **Add-Migration** and stored in the second part of the migration partial class and in the database when the database is created as binary stream varbinary(max).

When the database initializer (Database.SetInitializer) is called, then EF generate from the classes on the fly(**Runtime**) the current Entity Data Model(*EDMX*). The generated model will be serialized, zipped(base64) and finally compare it with the stored Model of the migration history table.

The comparison happens before the DbContext is created and, if the two Models(binary streams) are not identical then you will get a ***compatibility exception***.